# How to fix 'Legal Content missing' error while creating LeadGen Form through Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create LeadgenForm using remote_create() in Python. I have added the privacy policy details in LeadGenLegalContent. But with the given details, Lead generation form was not created. Any clue on the following error?

> Status:  400
>     Response:
>       {
>         "error": {
>           "code": 100, 
>           "is_transient": false, 
>           "error_subcode": 1892075, 
>           "error_user_msg": "Either legal_content_id or privacy_policy is required to be specified to create a LeadGen form", 
>           "error_user_title": "Legal content missing", 
>           "message": "Invalid parameter", 
>           "type": "OAuthException", 
>           "fbtrace_id": "GNmKk1KZxmm"
>         }
>       }

The idea is to create Lead Ad using API. I am able to create Campaign, Adset, Creative and Ad for an existing Form (using lead_gen_form_id). When I tried to create new form using LeadGenLegalContent, the above message is displayed.

```
leadgenquestion = LeadGenQuestion(parent_id = facebook_page_id)
leadgenquestion[LeadGenQuestion.Field.type] ='EMAIL'
leadgenquestion[LeadGenQuestion.Field.key] = 'question1'

leadgenlegalcontent = LeadGenLegalContent(parent_id = facebook_page_id)
leadgenlegalcontent[LeadGenLegalContent.Field.privacy_policy] = {'url': fbil_url, 'link_text' : 'Read the Privacy Policy'}

leadgenform = LeadgenForm(facebook_page_id)             
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.name] = 'Form Name'
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.follow_up_action_url] = fbil_url
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.questions] = leadgenquestion
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.legal_content] = leadgenlegalcontent 
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.status] = LeadgenForm.Status.active                     
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.privacy_policy_url] = fbil_url
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.created_time] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
leadgenform[LeadgenForm.Field.locale] = 'EN_US'        
leadgenform.remote_create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need the legal_content_id. You can get it with this:

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com//v3.2/PAGE_ID/leadgen_legal_content?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

Your access token has to be from page, so before that:

```
curl -X GET 'https://graph.facebook.com//v3.2/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

where the second are the user access token.

Then I just add like a simple field to my new form. In your case it has to be like:

```
leadgenform["legal_content_id"] = "<legal_content_id>"

leadgenform.remote_create()
```

Comment: as of April 2019, leadgen_legal_content is discontinued.